# Draw circles without getting previous circle removed

Tags: java, android

I am currently drawing circles everytime I click on the screen but when I draw one circle the previous one that I had drawn gets erased. Is there a way to keep clicking and having the previous circle stay on the screen?

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            drawCirc = true;
            xTouch = event.getX();
            Log.d("keyboard", "xpos" + xTouch);
            yTouch = event.getY();
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            drawCirc = false;
    }
    return true;
}


public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    if(drawCirc) {
        if (xTouch < 150 && xTouch>0) {
                paint.setColor(Color.RED);
                canvas.drawCircle(150, 500, 100, paint);
                invalidate();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you are asking. You are drawing a circle in the same location with the same size and the same color everytime, what do you mean by "the previous one gets erased"?

Comment: @MaxVollmer hi, sorry I haven't put all of my code but I have it so where if I click a different region on the screen it'll put a circle but will delete the previous circle. I want to know if there is a way to have all stay on the screen.

Comment: We cannot help you if you don't show us the actual code. Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your question with a [MCVE]. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're not saving the `old` points. You need to create a list of pairs, or a map and save all points.

```
final List<Pair<Integer, Integer> points = new ArrayList();

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            drawCirc = true;
            xTouch = event.getX();
            Log.d("keyboard", "xpos" + xTouch);
            yTouch = event.getY();
            points.add(new Pair(xTouch, yTouch));
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            drawCirc = false;
    }
    return true;
}


public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    if(drawCirc) {
        for (Pair<Int, Int> point : points) {
            xTouch = point.first;
            yTouch = point.second;
            if (xTouch < 150 && xTouch>0) {
                paint.setColor(Color.RED);
                canvas.drawCircle(150, 500, 100, paint);
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

The code above should give you a rough idea on what to do.